# GitLab, Redmine integration issues - Bitnami stack on different machines

Tags: git, redmine, gitlab, bitnami, redmine-plugins

I am trying to do the following with my GitLab, Redmine installs (different machines, using Bitnami Stack - Redmine on Windows, GitLab on Ubuntu).

1. From GitLab comments be able to get to Redmine
2. From Redmine issues see the associated commits

W.r.t #1, I have been able to link GitLab with one project. However, I have multiple projects in Redmine - the main project corresponds to trunk and subprojects correspond to "branches" off main. I would like to be able to get to all issues irrespective of projects.

W.r.t #2, I have set up the repository configuration setting to use Git and pointed it to the local Git repository. However, I don't see the changesets with issues. I tried using the following plugin https://github.com/phlegx/redmine_gitlab_hook but ran into issues.

How do I achieve the two scenarios mentioned?

Comment: I followed the information here http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_keep_in_sync_your_git_repository_for_redmine and got the initial sync working and the changesets to show up. Still trying to figure out the ongoing sync/ changesets. I am not sure if I need to run rake redmine:fetch_changesets